# Запись в базу данных которые приходят с формы

Tags: php

Не могу разобраться как записать данные в базу есть массив с данными

```
[product_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [product_name] => Часы1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [product_name] => Часы2
            )

    )

[model_product] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [model_product] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [model_product] => 
            )

    )

[total] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [total] => 25
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [total] => 25
            )

    )

[quantity] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [quantity] => 2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [quantity] => 1
            )

    )

[oll_total] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [oll_total] => 50
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [oll_total] => 25
            )

    )
```

у меня есть метод который мне выдает id заказа

```
$order_id = $this->db->getLastId();
```

Как мне сделать что бы в базу записывались данные

```
id  id_order  product_name  total   model_product
1   1              name1      1        model1
2   2              name2      3        model2
```

Вот форма отправки данных

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;
    $("#add_row").click(function(){
        $('#addr'+i).html("<td><input type='ext' name='product_name[][product_name]' required class='form-control'></td>" +
            "<td><input name='model_product[][model_product]' type='text' class='form-control' /></td>" +
            "<td><input type='text' name='total[][total]' required class='form-control' id='i1'  onchange='simplecheckout_reload(this);'></td>" +
            "<td><img src='/catalog/view/theme/default/assets/images/add/minus.png' border='0' onclick='jQuery(this).next().val(~~jQuery(this).next().val()-1); simplecheckout_reload(this);'>" +
            "<input type='text' name='quantity[][quantity]' id=i2  value='1' size='1' onchange='simplecheckout_reload(this);'>" +
            "<img src='/catalog/view/theme/default/assets/images/add/plus.png' border='0' onclick='jQuery(this).prev().val(~~jQuery(this).prev().val()+1);simplecheckout_reload(this);'></td>" +
            "<td><input type='text' name='oll_total[][oll_total]' id=i3></td>" +
            "<td><a id='delete_row' style='margin-right:30%;' class='pull-right minus'><i class='fa fa-minus' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></td></td>");

        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
        i++;
    });
    $("#delete_row").click(function(){
        if(i > 1 ){
            $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
            i--;
        }
    });
});

jQuery(document).on('click', '.minus', function(){
  jQuery( this ).closest( 'tr' ).remove();
  });

function simplecheckout_reload(element){
var row = $(element).closest("tr");

var n1 = row.find("input[name='total[][total]']").val();
var n2 = row.find("input[name='quantity[][quantity]']").val();
row.find("input[name='oll_total[][oll_total]']").val(Number(n1) * Number(n2));
}
```

Comment: вы сами придумали такой входной формат данных? зачем данные разбивать на 5 массивов с 2 полями, если можно сделать 2 элемента на каждый продукт с 5ю полями внутри?

Comment: Я добавил форму отправки, я долго делал (мучился) c формой отправки если можете подскажите как можно сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам, как верно подметил teran, неоходимо переделать структуру отправляемых в обработчик массивов в $_post (если я правильно понимаю, это всё набор одного заказа).

```
<input name='order_id' />
<input name='product_name[]' /> // опускаю прочие атрибуты элемента для наглядности
<input name='product_model[] />
<input name='total[]' />
<input name='quantity[] />
```

Это позволит передать следующую структуру:

```
[product_name] => Array(
    [0] => Часы1
    [1] => Часы2
)

[product_model => Array(
    [0] => model1
    [1] => model2
)

[total] => Array(
    [0] => 25
    [1] => 25
)

[quantity] => Array(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 1
)
```

На каждый input создаётся массив значений. Передаются они в том же порядке, что и выстраиваются. Соответственно индексы элементов каждого массива будут совпадать и на основании этого, обрабатывая данные перед формирование запроса, вы строите наборы.

```
if($_post): // надеемся, что post
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_post); $i++):
        $processed_pn = strip_tags($_post['product_name'][$i]);
        ...
        //do some data processing
        ...
        $query = "insert into `your_table`(id_order, product_name, ...) values ($order_id, $processed_pn, ...);";
    endfor;

    $this->db->query($query); // образно, я не знаю ваши методы, вы не указали

endif;
```

Описан случал добавления записей, getLastId() не нужен. Он понадобится при обновлении записей.